# Holonomy expansion for path deformation

Tags: differential-geometry, field-theory, gauge-theory, wilson-loop

A path deformation by $\epsilon^{\mu}(s)$ induces a variation of the connection $A'(s)=A(s)+\Delta A(s)$. I'm trying to obtain the first-order expansion of the holonomy $H_{\gamma}(A)=Pe^{i\int_{\gamma}A}$:

$\Delta H_{\gamma}=i\int_0^1dt[Pe^{i\int_0^tdsA(s)}]\Delta A(t)[Pe^{i\int_t^1dsA(s)}]$

Maybe my problem only is: how does the path-ordering operator work during the expansion?